# Zuul routes to services with nested path

Tags: rest, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to configure Netflix Zuul routes to two microservices (which are based on spring boot).

- First microservice **foo** is accessible with path `/foo/**`
- Second microservice **bar** is accessible with path `/foo/*/bar/**`

I was trying something like this, but dosen't work:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    foo: /foo/**
    bar: /foo/*/bar/**
```

Is possible such configuration, when paths are nested?

Configuration like this is required, because `/bar/` *subresource* is operated by **bar** microservice.

Context on foo: `/foo/`

Context on bar: `/foo/*/bar/**`

Comment: It should, but order matters, foo takes precedence over bar in you current definition.

Comment: ok, but with corrected order still is not working

Comment: what is "not working"?

Comment: Maybe I receive 404 for `GET /foo/X/bar/Y/action`, because microservice *bar* is expecting to receive `GET /foo/X/bar/Y/action`? The `/foo/X/bar/Y/` is passed to *bar*?

Comment: Thanks, it works ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

```
zuul:
  routes:
    bar:
      path: /foo/*/bar/**
      serviceId: bar
      stripPrefix: false
    foo:
      path: /foo/**
      serviceId: foo
      stripPrefix: false
```